# Change Recordset Type via VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, dao

I have a MS-Access database, which includes several queries, which have the recordset type Dynaset. I want to change all Queries to the Recordset Type Snapshot (i.e. dbOpenSnapshot).

Following approach gives me the error message that dbOpenSnapshot is not a valid argument, which I took from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/recordset-type-property-dao)

```
Sub Properties()
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rsQuery As DAO.RecordSet
    
Set dbs = CurrentDb

Set rsQuery = dbs.OpenRecordset("Query1")
rsQuery.Properties("Type") = dbOpenSnapshot

End Sub
```

Thank you for any hints!

Comment: You need to work on the querydef object, not the recordset. The online help link is misleading.

Answer (score 2):

This is the syntax:

```vb
Set rsQuery = dbs.OpenRecordset("Query1", dbOpenSnapshot, dbReadOnly)
```

[Database.OpenRecordset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/database-openrecordset-method-dao?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002361)

Comment: Thank you very much! But when running the VBA-sub and opening the Query in MS Access gui the Recordset Type is still set to Dynaset.
Is it possible to change the Recordset Type via VBA, so it is persistent? Thank you!

Comment: Don't know. Using `dbOpenSnapshot` opens a snapshot for me. But you could open the recordset as read-only as well. See edited answer, please.

Comment: @JimmyKowalski I believe this is just the default property of the recordset type in the form's properties window. The query recordset type takes precedence though.